# How to Deploy an IO Function every 5 Minutes w/o Blocking (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell

**Context:** I have a simple IO function called `slowBlockingFunction` which sends a payload of data to a server. The problem is this function is slow and blocking, and I otherwise need real-time performance for the rest of my program.

**Question:** Is there way to repeatedly call `slowBlockingFunction` every 5 minutes in an async fashion (so it doesn't interfere with the other realtime performing code by blocking)? I suppose this would be moving it to a new thread somehow?

Comment: [forkIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO) or [withAsync](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:withAsync), then [threadDelay](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay)

Answer (score 3):

This could be done by starting a thread that repeatedly

1. starts another thread that just runs `slowBlockingFunction`, then
2. sleeps for 5 minutes and repeats.

Like this:

```
import Control.Concurrent

repeatedlyDoSlowStuffInBackground = forkIO doStuff
    where
    doStuff = do
        forkIO slowBlockingFunction
        threadDelay (1000 * 1000 * 60 * 5)
        doStuff
```

Then you just call `repeatedlyDoSlowStuffInBackground` somewhere once.

Note that this does not compensate for variable delays. E.g. it's possible for the thread to be delayed due to system load by, say, 2 seconds, in which case it's going to sleep for an additional 5 minutes instead of compensating by only sleeping for 4 minutes 58 seconds.

Comment: Here you're explicitly calling `forkIO` twice; is the initial `forkIO` necessary?

Comment: @George I recommend Simon Marlow's "Parallel and Concurrent Haskell" http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929 . You can probably start with chapter 7 to get a basic overview of threads, etc

Comment: @jberryman: Thanks for the recommendation. Is there anything dated in that book I should look out for?

Comment: No I don't think so.